# Are there programming languages that rely on non-latin alphabets?

Tags: programming-languages, alphabet, non-latin

Every programming language I have ever seen has been based on the Latin alphabet, this is not surprising considering I live in Canada...
But it only really makes sense that there would be programming languages based on other alphabets, or else bright computer scientists across the world would have to learn a new alphabet to go on in the field.  I know for a fact that people in countries dominated by other alphabets develop languages based off the Latin alphabet (eg. Ruby from Japan), but just how common is it for programming languages to be based off of other alphabets like Arabic, or Cyrillic, or even writing systems which are not alphabetic but rather logographic in nature such as Japanese Kanji?
Also are any of these languages in active widespread use, or are they mainly used as teaching tools?
This is something that has bugged me since I started programming, and I have never run across someone who could think of a real answer.

Comment: This is an objective scholarly question and has no reason to be community wiki.

Comment: Edited tags because (1) the question asks about non-Latin characters not about Latin characters, and (2) some tagger's definition of foreign isn't accurate for all programming language developers. The inventor of Ruby depended a lot on foreign non-Japanese characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English-based_programming_languages). I don't think any of them is really prevalent though. Many programmers can learn to write programs with english keywords even if they didn't understand the language. Ruby is a good example, you'll still see Japanese identifiers and comments in some Ruby code.

Comment: Phoenix (found in linked article), an Arabic programming language is what I was thinking of when I wrote this question. I suggest you all go look at it and see what a program looks like written right to left in another alphabet looks like. http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=161740

Comment: ChinesePython is awesome. =) Unfortunately the latest release was 6 years ago.

Comment: "you'll still see Japanese identifiers and comments in some Ruby code." -- True but you won't see the language itself DEPEND on those non-Latin alphabets.

Answer (score 36):

Have you seen Perl?

Answer (score 22):

[APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) is probably the most widely known.  It even has a cool keyboard overlay (or was it a special keyboard you had to buy?):

[image: image courtesy of Wikipedia]

In the non-alphabetic category, we also have programming languages like [LabVIEW](http://www.ni.com/labview/whatis/), which is mostly graphical.  (You can label objects, and you can still do string manipulation, so there's *some* textual content.)  LabVIEW has been used in data acquisition and automation for years, but gained a bit of popularity when it became the default platform for [Lego Mindstorms](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx).

Comment: @mpez0: I'm getting kind of old, but even I can't imagine programming on a machine that requires a typeball. :)

Comment: What was really cool was putting an APL typeball on a Selectric typewriter and watching it mess with people's minds :-)

Comment: APL is an interesting example of a non linguistic programming language which relies on it's own special symbols (I'm assuming, I haven't seen symbols like that used elsewhere). This was something I hadn't really considered.

Comment: Look up IBM 2741 Selectric Terminal.  Also available on 1130 and 360 consoles.

Comment: Most of the APL symbols were derived from mathematical notation, and so several of them have the same display as Greek letters (rho, iota, epsilon, alpha, omega, delta). There are non-latin, but APL fonts are widely available, and a special keyboard was never needed, although handy as a mnemonic device. The typeball hasn't been sued ina  very long time, although i can recall working on a terminal so equipped.

Answer (score 6):

Well, [Brainf*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) uses no latin characters, if you'll pardon the language...and the pun.

Answer (score 3):

Many languages allow Unicode identifiers.  It's part of [standard Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.1), and both [g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_status_of_adding_the_UTF-8_support_for_identifier_names_in_GCC.3F) (though you have to use \uNNNN escapes) and [MSVC++](http://www.siao2.com/2007/06/22/3466480.aspx) allow them (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331690/c-source-in-unicode))  And some allow using `#define` (or maybe better) to rename control structures.

But in reality, people don't do this for the most part.  See past questions such as [Language of variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506795/language-of-variable-names-native-foreign-language-speakers), [Should all code be written in English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425097/should-all-code-be-written-in-english), etc.

Comment: You mentioned Java before I would.  Note that the functional keywords are all in the section of unicode that maps to ASCII, but other names are not constrained by anything except the programmer's convention.

Answer (score 3):

[Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php).

Sample Snippet:

```
mutual
   data ωChain : Set where
     _∷_,_ : ∀ (x : carrier) (xω : ∞ ωChain) (p : x ≼ xω) → ωChain

   head : ωChain → carrier
   head (x ∷ _ , _) = x

   _≼_ : carrier → ∞ ωChain → Set
   x ≼ xω = x ≤ head (♭ xω)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's always [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)). That has its own UNICODE characters, and I believe it used to require a special keyboard too.

Comment: APL's characters were invented around 30 years before Unicode.  Unicode copied APL's characters for the same reason that Unicode copied other character sets, to make a unified character code.

Comment: @Windows: Yes. So? You still can't do it with a conventional character set.

Comment: RTFQ (Read The Question): "Are there programming languages that rely on non-latin alphabets?" It did not ask about punctuation marks. Next, RTFA (Read The Answer): "That has its own UNICODE characters". UNICODE is irrelevant and I explained why.

Comment: @Windows: I really don't agree with your assertion that it is an irrelevant answer. I just think you've chosen a silly stance and are defending it in the face of much evidence.

Answer (score 2):

There'is one langauge used in russian ERP system called after company, which developed it `1C`. But it's identifiers and operators has english analogs.

Also, I know that `haskell` has unicode identifiers support, so you can write programs in any alphabet. But this is not useful (My native language is russian). It's quite enough that you have to type program messages and helpful comments in native alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Other people are answering with languages that use punctuation marks in addition to Latin letters.  I wonder why no one mentioned digits 0 to 9 as well.

In some languages, and in some implementations of some languages, programmers can use a wide range of characters in identifiers, such as Arabic or Chinese characters.  This doesn't mean that the language relies on them though.

In most languages, programmers can use a wide range of characters in string literals (in quotation marks) and in comments.  Again this doesn't mean that the language relies on them.

In every programming language that I've seen, the language does rely on punctuation marks and digits.  So this answers your question but not in the way you expect.

Now let's try to find something meaningful.  Is there a programming language where keywords are chosen from non-Latin alphabets?  I would guess not, except maybe for joke languages.  What would be the point of inventing a programming language that makes it impossible for some programmers to even input a program?

EDIT:  My guess is wrong.  Besides APL's usage of various invented punctuation marks, it does depend on a few Greek keywords, where each keyword is one letter long, such as the letter rho.

Comment: @Windows programmer: How about languages that don't have key **words**?  At least two earlier posts mentioned APL, which is written in a mathematical syntax.

Comment: And how many non-Latin alphabetical letters are used in all zero of those words? (Except APL as added in my edit.)

Comment: "What would be the point of inventing a programming language that makes it impossible for some programmers to even input a program?"
surely this is the case for programmers starting a language like java when all they have ever seen is Arabic...

Comment: I think keyboards in Arab countries can input Latin letters as well as Arabic.

Comment: I think keyboards in English countries can (be configured to) input Arabic letters as well as Latin.

Comment: Yes, modern operating systems usually have drivers that let users input any language.  But I think keyboards in Arab countries have both Arabic and Latin characters imprinted on the keys themselves and it's probably trivial for users to switch between the two, so programmers who have only ever seen Arabic can probably start Java with Latin characters.  The reverse is not true.  Keyboards that I've seen in the UK, US, Indonesia, etc., have Latin letters but not Arabic, so users have to learn how to use their OS's drivers to input Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an interesting [wiki](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page) for "[esoteric programming languages](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language)".