# Unicode in QML/C++ issue

Tags: c++, unicode, qml

In QML I have a TextArea. When I set the text property of this TextArea to "ÆØÅ" it shows "ÆØÅ" when the program runs.

I also get text through some functions that I want to show in the same TextArea, but then "ÆØÅ" is shown as "???".

The strings come from this C++ function:

```
QString Tts::morseToChar(QString morse)
{
    if(morse == ".-")               return "A";
    else if (morse == "-...")       return "B";
    ...
    ...
    else if (morse == ".-.-")       return "Æ";
    else if (morse == "---.")       return "Ø";
    else if (morse == ".--.-")      return "Å";
}
```

The return string gets added to a QML string:

```
property string ttsChar: ""
ttsChar += ttsSpeak.morseToChar(morse)
_ttsTextArea.text += ttsChar
```

All files are saved as UTF-8.

What conversion am I missing to get this to work?

Comment: It's a bad idea to use non-ASCII character and string literals directly in the code. It is not portable and not scalable. Loading from text files at run time is preferred.

Comment: This application is to be used by one person on one machine only so if not necessary (even though a good idea/tip) I would like to keep it simple.

Comment: See, it's not even scalable to one person on one machine.

Comment: I see your point. I will try your way =)

Answer (score 3):

Try returning the [universal character name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) instead of the utf-8 representation.

```
QString Tts::morseToChar(QString morse)
{
    if(morse == ".-")               return "A";
    else if (morse == "-...")       return "B";
    ...
    ...
    else if (morse == ".-.-")       return u8"\u00C6";
    else if (morse == "---.")       return u8"\u00D8";
    else if (morse == ".--.-")      return u8"\u00C5";
}
```

You can search for universal character names [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) which is where the names for [Æ (\00C6)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c6/index.htm), [Ø (\00D8)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d8/index.htm) and [Å (\00C5)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c5/index.htm) were found.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/331935/1985643) for more information on why the utf-8 representation isn't allowed in c++ source files.

Answer (score 2):

The [default constructor for QStrings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#QString-8) from `char *` uses the `fromAscii()` function.

Chances are your strings are actually encoded in UTF-8, so there's two things to try:-

a : Return wide chars:

```
return L"Æ";
```

b: Or, explicitly convert from UTF8

```
 return QString::fromUtf8("Æ");
```

Comment: I tried returning wide char before asking, but got the error: C2664: 'QString::QString(QChar)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t [2]' to 'QChar'
No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous. I tried your alternative b) but that did not do any difference as well.