# Wrong encoding (utf 8 -> iso-8859-1) with copy-paste using Qt qml textfield with webassembly

Tags: qt, encoding, webassembly

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

In my application, when i use ctr+c to copy a text 'é' from a TextField (qml) and paste it in a extern utf-8 notepad. I got 'Ã©'.

I tried this html format parameter in a normal simple page html that work just fine for copy.

I'm using Qt5.12.4 to compile.

I don't kown how to change my text in clipboard in utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Qt default encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705488/set-qt-default-encoding-to-utf-8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode in QML/C++ issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330665/unicode-in-qml-c-issue)