# Using Greek symbols in C++ code

Tags: c++, variables, environment

I used to use greek symbols  like α and ε in my variable declaration in c++ code without problems. I changed the platform to Ubuntu and I started getting errors like these during the compilation:

```
stray ‘\316’ in progra
stray ‘\261’ in program
```

Can I fix this problem without having to change my code?

Comment: Have you tried gcc's `-finput-charset=<charset>`? Checked now, utf-8 should be the default.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331690/c-source-in-unicode for some thoughts.

Comment: I am using intel compiler not gcc

Comment: If I understand the “basic source character set” correctly, you quite simply can’t do that. The basic source character set comprises exactly 96 characters, and there is no guarantee that, no matter what file encoding you use, characters outside this set can be mapped into the basic source character set.

Comment: @KonradRudolph C++11 allows Unicode characters in names.

Comment: Intel compiler supports this but you are not using it, you are using gcc. These are gcc error messages. icc has different error messages.

Answer (score 2):

In MSVC 2012 there would be no problem, you can download the greek language and write code as if you typed english, so the following is totally valid

```
#include <iostream>

#define ακέραιος int
#define για      for 
#define τυπωθήτω std::cout
#define πέρας    std::endl;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    για (ακέραιος αριθμός(0); αριθμός < 5; ++αριθμός)
    {
        τυπωθήτω << αριθμός << πέρας;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Other than that I haven't found an easy/natural way to use Greek with c++ code (or a reason to be fair)

NOTE: It's not an exception that VS does with Greek, it supports any language and I got the tip from reading a blog about writing c++ code in Hebrew

Comment: The question is about compilation on Ubuntu. This does not answer the question.  Unless you can explain how to make MSVC run on Linux and produce Linux binaries, that is.

Comment: Then edit the title **Using Greek symbols in C++ code** to **Using Greek symbols in C++ code compiled in Ubuntu** or something (in which case I'd be happy to delete the answer). As long as someone can google their way to this question, searching for c++ in general, the answer is posted for completeness.

Comment: What do you mean by “download the greek language”?

Comment: Getting the language for your OS, being able to type in Greek essentially (as opposed to entering a character's code from the Unicode Table)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Feel free to edit that bit out if it's impecise/misleading

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use greek characters in symbol names for C and C++ programs in Ubuntu with both the `gcc` and `clang` compilers.

For `gcc`, you may need to use the compiler options `-finput-charset=utf-8` and/or `-fextended-identifiers` to make it work. However, in most situations, you won't need these. In particular, if your locale's character set is already configured as UTF-8, which has been the default on Debian/Ubuntu for over a decade by now, you won't need to use `-finput-charset`. Check the `$LANG` environment variable to find out your locale's character set. Furthermore, `-fextended-identifiers` is the default for all recent versions of C and C++. In case, that you run `gcc` with some compiler options to select an antique version of C or C++, `-fextended-identifiers` will be off by default and you may need to specify it. But then, how come, that the antique code, that requires the antique compiler mode, has modern UTF-8 identifiers in it.

`clang` also supports the `-finput-charset` option and reading the input character set from the user's locale. And, again, don't switch to an antique compiler mode to compile a file, that has modern UTF-8 identifiers in it.