# How to search an utf8 characters?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, utf-8, cjk

So I am using C++11, and the input is a text file encoded in UTF-8 encoding, and what the program does is to read the text file line by line, and search whether a given character is present in the line, since UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII, that means new line is same in ASCII and UTF-8, I'm not using `wstring`, I'm just using `string`, what I do is get the UTF-8 encoded bytes, and create a `std::string` of that, e.g., I need to search for `值(U+503C)` in each line, and from [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/503c/index.htm) we can see the UTF-8 encoded bytes for this character is `0xE5 0x80 0xBC`, so I have something like this, does this look right and will work?

```
ifstream input(utf8file);
string line;
const string t("\xe5\x80\xbc"); // utf8 bytes for 值
while (input) {
    getline(input, line);
    if (line.find(t) != string::npos) {
        do_found();
    } else {
        not_found();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: is the code right? :)

Comment: Look good for me.

Comment: will `const string t("值");` work?

Comment: Look at [using-unicode-in-c-source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331690/using-unicode-in-c-source-code)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `while (input)` checks the state of the stream **before** each `getline`; there is no check that the call to `getline` succeeded before examining the result. Combine the two with `while (std::getline(input, line))`.

Comment: ok, makes sense, question is more on what should I use for the `const string t` line?

Comment: @fluter What operating system is this for?

Comment: @WBuck it is on Linux, but does OS matters?